# unittest main module python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the following main module:

```
import pandas as pd
from formatting import abs_value, api_call

def main():

    dataframe2 = abs_value(dataframe1)

    dataframe3 = api_call(dataframe2)
```

The main module is just using various functions (abs_value and api_call) in another module called formatting to perform updates to a dataframe. I have unittested the formatting module to 100% but my main is at 20%. When I test the main, it actually tries to run the various functions so I assume I have to mock this? The end result of my main has no result so it would be "return None". I would like to assert that this occurs at the end, but am unsure conceptually of how to proceed.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you can't test your `main()` method in exactly the same way you are testing your other code?

Comment: Also the code as should will fail because `dataframe1` isn't defined...

Comment: You could Mock `abs_value` and `api_call` to make sure `main` called them once each with the expected params but honestly, do you need 100% coverage here ?